# Want to get the array of form element's value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

**HTML Form code**

```
<form ng-submit="mysubmit()" ng-controller="question_post" >
    <textarea name="question" id="question" ng-model="question"></texarea> 
    <input type="text" name="opt[]" ng-model="opt[]" />
    <input type="text" name="opt[]" ng-model="opt[]" />
</form>
```

**Angular JS Code**

```
var obj = angular.module('root', []);

obj.controller('question_post', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.mysubmit = function(){
    $http({
        url: "some_url",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data:$.param({user_id:1,'question':$scope.question,'option':$scope.opt})
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
                alert(data);
                $scope.data = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
        });
        }
   }]);
```

The code above returns error when I write `ng-model="opt[]"`, and `ng-model="opt"` returns a value.

I'm trying to add the dynamic text fields with name `opt`, and for this I want to get the `opt` value in an array.
If I'm using PHP then its okay `($option =$_POST['opt'])` but how can I get the array value of `opt` in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the options within your controller, pass it along to the view and use `ng-repeat` to iterate over your options. This way you could use `$index` and save your options into an array. Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ptbc63Epc6ZYE0lngoIJ?p=preview) as an example.

So basically you iterate over your options, as mentioned:

```
<div ng-repeat="option in vm.options">
  <input type="text" name="{{ option.name }}" ng-model="vm.opt[$index]" />
```

As you can see I used `ng-model` like this:

```
ng-model="vm.opt[$index]"
```

This will save the value of the input field in an array at the position of `$index`, which is much like the iterator in a for-loop and starts with 0.